# Change post type name without losing custom field values

Tags: mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-fields

I need to change the name of one of my custom post types. These posts have several custom fields associated with them. After changing the name, I update the name of the post types in the database and all of the posts appear again in Wordpress. However, they seem to have lost their custom field information. Is this also updatable?

Comment: `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` are linked via `wp_posts.ID` in the database so changing the `wp_posts.post_type` shouldn't effect postmeta custom fields. Can you give a little more info on how you apply custom values to posts?

Answer (score 1):

Just Run following query in your wp_posts

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_type`='<old-value>' WHERE `post_type`='new value';
```

Do remember to enter your old post type name and new post type name, changing post type name will not effect custom fields as meta fields are associated with post id only.

Cheers...

Comment: As I mentioned I was already able to update the post type name, however all image and repeater fields appear blank after doing so.